# Root Folder works with ./ and not with /

Tags: html, css, directory, root

I was linking my external css file to the header of my page, like this

```
<head>
<link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

But the styling wasn't working until I added a dot to the path, like this

```
<head>
<link href="./css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

I have tried it in Firefox, Chrome, Mozilla and Opera and everywhere was the same result.
How can this be possible? Since in all the sites I have searched, they indicate that to go up to the root folder you just need to type "/css/style.css" without a dot.
Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: For root you need to use ./ or ../   What is problem in using a dot??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It always depends in which folder you css file is. if you have a structure like this:

```
-index.html
-css (folder)
--style.css
```

than you can write css/style.css, but if it is like this

```
-pages (folder)
--index.html
-css (folder)
--style.css
```

than you have to add a ./css/style.css because "./" means to get a folder back bevore entering the css folder

Comment: Yes my structure is like the second. But in the example I followed it doesn't mention that I have to put

Answer (score 0):

The **.** mean's

> one folder back/[path]

normaly u write **../[path]**

**EDIT:**

i dont know how your Folder architektur look's like, and if you using JQuery or Javascript for loadin's that's important informations..